# Magento Block not rendering/Instantiating

Tags: magento

I created a custom block (by creating a module and doing a layout update via an xml file), and the block is not rendering for some reason.

I have commercebug installed so i checked the layout xml for the page and it shows that it updated with the proper info, but when I go to the blocks tab it's not there (and not calling it)

this block rendered nicely on my local machine but on the staging server it doesn't work (even though i copied the files etc.)

I am a beginner so any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance,
pesach

Comment: 1. Try clearing your cache. 2. Turn on Template Path Hints & Add Block Names to Hints and you'll be able to see what layouts/blocks are being loaded, that might give you some clues.

Comment: 1. i cleared the cache already 2. that's the issue i'm having it's not coming up there but in the layout xml it is. (i''m using commercebug from alan storm to see this info live)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're saying you've successfully added some Layout XML to the page layout.  If you could post that it would help people debug your problem better.

The next three steps to take are

1. Ensure your block type is correct
2. Ensure your template file (if you're using one) exists
3. Ensure the block you're inserting your custom block into will automatically render blocks (i.e. is a text_list block)

If you post the actual layout xml you've added the page layout, we'll be able to help with the items above.